# Linux network device watchdog timer mechanism

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm studying Linux network device driver with Linux 4.12.14, and here is what I've learnt:

1. In device driver, it sets some variables when the device is opened:

   ```
   dev->watchdog_timeo = TX_TIMEOUT;
   ...
   .ndo_tx_timeout     = el3_tx_timeout,
   ```
2. Linux kernel activates a timer when the device is opened:

   ```
   static void dev_watchdog(unsigned long arg)
   {
       struct net_device *dev = (struct net_device *)arg;

       netif_tx_lock(dev);
       if (!qdisc_tx_is_noop(dev)) {
           if (netif_device_present(dev) &&
               netif_running(dev) &&
               netif_carrier_ok(dev)) {
               int some_queue_timedout = 0;
               unsigned int i;
               unsigned long trans_start;

               for (i = 0; i < dev->num_tx_queues; i++) {
                   struct netdev_queue *txq;

                   txq = netdev_get_tx_queue(dev, i);
                   trans_start = txq->trans_start;
                   if (netif_xmit_stopped(txq) &&
                       time_after(jiffies, (trans_start +
                                dev->watchdog_timeo))) {
                       some_queue_timedout = 1;
                       txq->trans_timeout++;
                       break;
                   }
               }

               if (some_queue_timedout) {
                   WARN_ONCE(1, KERN_INFO "NETDEV WATCHDOG: %s (%s): transmit queue %u timed out\n",
                          dev->name, netdev_drivername(dev), i);
                   dev->netdev_ops->ndo_tx_timeout(dev);
               }
               if (!mod_timer(&dev->watchdog_timer,
                          round_jiffies(jiffies +
                                dev->watchdog_timeo)))
                   dev_hold(dev);
           }
       }
       netif_tx_unlock(dev);

       dev_put(dev);
   }
   ```

   So, after kernel transfers a skb, it updates txq->trans_start:

   ```
   static inline netdev_tx_t netdev_start_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev,
                           struct netdev_queue *txq, bool more)
   {
       const struct net_device_ops *ops = dev->netdev_ops;
       int rc;

       rc = __netdev_start_xmit(ops, skb, dev, more);
       if (rc == NETDEV_TX_OK)
           txq_trans_update(txq);

       return rc;
   }
   ```

   And the function to update txq->trans_start:

   ```
   static inline void txq_trans_update(struct netdev_queue *txq)
   {
       if (txq->xmit_lock_owner != -1)
           txq->trans_start = jiffies;
   }
   ```

However, I didn't find anywhere updates the "txq->trans_start" again, so my question is:
**How come a successful transmit doesn't make the watchdog timer timeout?**

Comment: *->start_xmit()* is called many times  if I understand correctly.